# why is my JSONB query no returning any result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

A look at my JSONB field

```
select internet_address from resporg_account_ids where id=3
=> [{"zone": "us-central1", "address": "127.0.0.1", "reserve": true}, {"zone": "us-east1", "address": "127.0.0.10", "reserve": true}
```

]

Relevant jsonb query

```
select * from resporg_account_ids where internet_address <@ '[{"zone": "us-central1", "address": "127.0.0.1", "reserve": true}]'::jsonb;
```

and this

```
select * from resporg_account_ids where internet_address <@ '{"zone": "us-central1", "address": "127.0.0.1", "reserve": true}'::jsonb;
```

And I see no result in my output console.

Also,  I would like to query it based on an individual key(s)...

Like

```
select * from resporg_account_ids where internet_address->>address="127.0.0.1" and internet_address->>reserve=true
```

Finally,

```
jsondb=# select version();
                                                    version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.10 on x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Note:

PART 1: is solved thanks @mroman for pointing that out.

Comment: `a <@ b` means A is contained within B, not B is contained within A. You probably need to either flip the arguments or use `@>`. But I'm not sure that these operands can be used on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotes for json keys of the object:

```
select * from resporg_account_ids where internet_address->>'address'='127.0.0.1'
```

In the second part you are trying to compare text with boolean, because `->>` returns text. So you need to cast type:

```
... and (internet_address->>'reserve')::boolean is true
```

Comment: ```views_production=# select * from resporg_account_ids where internet_address->>'address'="127.0.0.1"


views_production-# ;
ERROR:  column "127.0.0.1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rg_account_ids where internet_address->>'address'="127.0.0.1...```

Comment: @Ratatouille, I'm sorry, my mistake, just fixed it. Use single quotes for strings instead of double:
`internet_address->>'address'='127.0.0.1'`
Double quotes are used to refer to table attributes that contain upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

CTE comes to rescue...

```
with intaddr as (select jsonb_array_elements(internet_address) internetaddr from resporg_account_ids)
select * from intaddr where internetaddr->>'address' = '127.0.0.1' and (internetaddr->>'reserve')::boolean=true;
```